# How can I configure the firewall with node js?

Tags: node.js, firewall

How can I configure the firewall with node js?Could you give me a sample project?

Answer (score 3):

A firewall is a completely different piece of network infrastructure than node.js which is an application environment.  So while the two may be used in the same deployment, they are different tools for different jobs.  You would not typically "configure the firewall with nodejs".  Your firewall would usually have its own admin interface that you can login to and then make configuration changes.

If your firewall had a secure HTTP API for doing firewall administration, you could build a node.js app to login and then send HTTP requests to the firewall to modify its configuration.  The details of how to do that depend entirely upon what the HTTP API is in the firewall so we'd need to see that in order to recommend anything more specific.  In general, one can make an HTTP request from a node.js app to another HTTP server using the [`request-promise` module in NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise).

Comment: So Can I do with Ssh or Telnet?

Comment: @BurakKarabıyık - Go look at the documentation for your firewall and see what type of interface and connection it supports for configuring it.  This isn't something we can answer for you.  You have to go look at the doc for your specific firewall.  My home firewall uses a browser interface for configuring it.  I have no idea what yours does.  It depends entirely upon the particular brand and model.

Comment: I will try.Thank you for all.

Answer (score 1):

Both Windows and Mac (and of course Linux) enable you to view and modify the firewall settings via some kind of command line tool.

For example, this [post](https://www.windows-commandline.com/enable-disable-firewall-command-line/) talks about modifying Windows firewall settings through the `netsh` command, and this [post](https://krypted.com/mac-security/command-line-firewall-management-in-os-x-10-10/) covers command line firewall management in OSX (Mac).

Since `Node.js` is able to execute command line commands via [Child Processes](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html), theoretically, you can modify a system's firewall settings through code running in `Node.js`.

There's also an `npm` package called [firewall](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firewall) which claims to "Add or remove system firewall rules using Node.js.".

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid question. Network firewall and application firewall both can co-exist together.